# ActionBar - Using a View as icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, actionbarsherlock

So, I want to use a View in place of the app icon in the actionbar. I can't use a simple image because the View will change its colours depending of the set of colors chosen in the parameters of the app (and I don't want to create four hundred images in photoshop...).

I know I can use a custom view for the action bar and it's even quiet easy, but the problem is that the original app image is still shown. I also know that I can hide it by setting `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled` to false, but that also hides the glyph of my navigation drawer and that is the problem.

I also tried to create a custom Drawable and override the onDraw method but nothing was shown and the Drawable has 1px height/width.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the icon you can use a transparent one,   edit the style you use for your actionbar like this :

```
   <style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
     <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item> 
   </style>
```

assuming you use as style named `MyActionBarStyle` for your actionbar in your theme.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
     <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hiding the icon works, but the space used by the image is still there so my View can't align on the far left of the bar.

Comment: Have you considered, hiding both logo and navigation glyph and replicating the navigation functionality in your custom view with something like an image button?

Comment: I'm using the NavigationDrawer, so It would be hard to mimic the origin behaviour (especially the image translation during the opening/closing). I'd rather find a solution for replacing the image with a View I can override the onDraw method because if I use a custom view in the actionbar, the user can't even touch the image or the title to open the drawer or go up.

Comment: I see that ActionBarSherlock  is using the id `@id/abs__home` for the image. You could probably get hold of the imageView by its id and just hide it. Another aproach might be customizing the ActionBarSherlock library to just hide that. For example by editing the res/layout/abs__action_bar_home.xml and changing the visibility of the `ImageView` to Gone.

Comment: ABS uses the real ActionBar on devices running a high API level, so that won't work.